# Redirect domain name to a specific page

Tags: google-search, htaccess, url, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

I have theses domain names installed:

- Main domain name: `www.example.com`
- Others domains:

  - `www.example.org`
  - `www.example.fr`
  - `www.animals.example`

I first made a rule on my *.htaccess* to redirect all traffic from theses domain names into my main domain `www.example.com` with the HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have then a rule to rewrite my URL like that :

```
RewriteRule   ^([a-z]{2})-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$   index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2  [L]
```

The structure of my URLs are: `https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html` I need to promote this page on internet, but the URL is pretty difficult to remember and my main domain name: `www.example.com` is too generic.

I do have 2 very specific and important pages on my website that I want to promote though an easy to remember and short URL, so I bought the domain name: `www.animals.example`. I want that my visitors arrive on this page `https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html` with this (easy to remember) URL: `ww.animals.example`.

What is the best practice regarding Search Engines (Google)? Is it a good idea, good practice to do it?

Should I make a 301 redirection, so I can give to people this `www.animals.example` URL to visit my page, they will be then redirected and their browser will display `https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html`

Or is there a possibility to print `www.animals.example` as the URL on the browser when `https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html` is called?

How can I implement this in the most Google Friendly way?

Comment: Search engines mostly ignore redirected domains, so how you handle the redirect isn't going to have much impact on search engines.

Comment: solution would depend on where you want to promote these pages on, if your audience is coming via search and your page ranks are good then you don't need to simplify the URLs at all ( so no need for the simplified domain names and redirect) or if you expect the traffic to come directly by typing in URL in the browser than you need the simplified URLs

Answer (score 1):

Well you can redirect www.animal.example website to that example.com/whatever by using js (JavaScript)
Or PHP too.
It will not affect anything regarding to SEO (Search engine optimization)
**JavaScript:**

```
<script>windows.location = "https://example.com/whatever"; </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
header(" Location: https://example.com/whatever");
?>
```